# Ubuntu update gone wrong

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, updates, partial-upgrade

I tried to update to 12.10, but in the mist of installing, the entire computer froze, and not knowing about REISUB I forced quit my computer

Ever since, every time I updated, I was given a message that said to do a partial install (which I ignored. And a dialog box that said to run a command to fix the software updater. I would update the software, and halfway though installation, the computer would freeze, again

I repeated this thinking that next time this wouldn't happen, but after I rebooted, the desktop seemed broken, appearing only as a back screen that would act like an old frozen windows XP computer (in that when you move a application around the screen, it 'paints' a picture of the application on the desktop)

I tried again, it froze, and I REISUB

I tried again, it froze, and I REISUB

now, I'm at a blue screen of death. The entire screen is blue. But all of the processes still work, i just cant get to them without a keyboard shortcut.

So how do I fix this disastrous mess?

Oh, one more thing, it seems like the system is in this weird state where half of it is in 12.04 and half of its in 12.10, ever since the first try at updating failed.
The login screen says that I'm in 12.04, but the ctrl-alt-f1 terminal says I'm in 12.10

Answer (score 0):

Try going into "recovery mode" from the GRUB boot. Then, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and see if that gets you any more progress. If not, let us know what error output messages you get.

Comment: What do I select in the recovery menu?

Comment: Judging by the errors I received, it can't update because its not connected to the Internet (I'm in the root shell prompt)

Comment: Ok, I logged in not in recovery mode and went to the ctrl-alt-F1 terminal and ran those commands. At sudo apt-update it gave me an output of 373 packages that have been kept back. I'm pretty sure those packages are important, so how do I install them?