# update to 20.04 gone wrong - cannot boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, xubuntu, 20.04

I have a Dell Latitude 6430u dual boot Xubuntu 18.04 and Windows 7

Today I tried upgrading to 20.04 but during the process I got some error messages which said something to the effect that the upgrade did not finish and that the system may be unstable. I took screenshot of those messages (but I cannot access anymore as I left them on my desktop folder) and proceeded to shutdown normally.

Hours later I tried to boot up and I only see a black screen. I can boot into windows 7 without a problem. Next time I try to boot I get something that looks like a command shell and one of the error messages says "Unable to mount root fs on..."

Then I try booting into an older Kernel. It still doesn't work but this seems to get me a little further: I am able to see the Xubuntu logo and the spinning wheel beneath it. But just a black screen afterwards.

I tried booting in recovery mode on an older kernel and do dpkg (repair broken packages) but that didn't seem to fix anything.

Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283419/ubuntu-update-gone-wrong) I did sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade but I got the following error message: "1407 not fully installed or removed" This was at the same time that it asked me if I wanted to continue. I chose no.

That's where I stand now and I'm out of ideas. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live DVD or thumb drive and install it from there?

Make sure you have a backup of your files. Of course, you may not be able to get to them if you don't do backups.

Comment: So do a fresh install? I did backup my files just before attempting to upgrade but I was wondering if I could still salvage the situation and avoid a fresh install.

Comment: From a personal perspective, I almost always reinstall from a live cd. Historically works better for me. My files backup  on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to run a `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and answer YES to the question, whether I want to continue.

If this doesn't work, you may try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` instead.

Hopefully, it will complete the installation of 20.04.

Then I would run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove old packages that are no longer needed.

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it did not work. I get a lot of "dpkg: error processing package" and one error at the end that reads "E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: I added another alternative.

Comment: After running dpkg I caught a line that said "error running python..." before disappearing. The last line says " processing was halted because there were too many errors"